# Export scraping data in multiple formats using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, exporter

I'm scraping a website to export the data into a semantic format (n3).
However, I also want to perform some data analysis on that data, so having it in a csv format is more convenient.

To get the data in both formats I can do

```
scrapy spider -t n3 -o data.n3
scrapy spider -t csv -o data.csv
```

However, this scrapes the data twice and I cannot afford it with big amounts of data.

**Is there a way to export the same scraped data into multiple formats?** (without downloading the data more than once)

I find interesting to have an intermediate representation of the scraped data that could be exported into different formats. But it seems there is no way to do this with scrapy.

Comment: As alecxe suggested, I posted a feature request at scrapy's github https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1336

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I understand after exploring the source code and the documentation, [`-t` option refers to the `FEED_FORMAT` setting](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/342cb622f1ea93268477da557099010bbd72529a/scrapy/commands/crawl.py#L48) which cannot have multiple values. Also, the `FeedExporter` built-in extension ([source](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/342cb622f1ea93268477da557099010bbd72529a/scrapy/extensions/feedexport.py#L139)) works with a single exporter only.

Actually, think about making a *feature request* at the [Scrapy Issue Tracker](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/).

As more like a workaround, define a **pipeline** and start *exporting with multiple exporters*. For example, here is how to export into both CSV and JSON formats:

```
from collections import defaultdict

from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.exporters import JsonItemExporter, CsvItemExporter


class MyExportPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.files = defaultdict(list)

     @classmethod
     def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
         pipeline = cls()
         crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
         crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
         return pipeline

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        csv_file = open('%s_products.csv' % spider.name, 'w+b')
        json_file = open('%s_products.json' % spider.name, 'w+b')

        self.files[spider].append(csv_file)
        self.files[spider].append(json_file)

        self.exporters = [
            JsonItemExporter(json_file),
            CsvItemExporter(csv_file)
        ]

        for exporter in self.exporters:
            exporter.start_exporting()

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        for exporter in self.exporters:
            exporter.finish_exporting()

        files = self.files.pop(spider)
        for file in files:
            file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        for exporter in self.exporters:
            exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```

Comment: Ok, this is suitable solution, although I'd like to be able to configure the whole exporting using arguments. This way, I can only edit the `settings.py` to change the exporting configuration.